# Comparing cells from different excel worksheets and return if any value is repeated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I want to compare multiple worksheets and check if there is any cell that has repeated value. e.g. lts say I have worksheets WS1, WS2, WS3, WS4, WS5. each of these worksheets have data from cells A1 through H10.

Now lets say I have another worksheet named "RWS". I want A1 call entry in RWS to be 1 if A1 cells in Ws1 through WS5 has all different values and 0 if any of those values is repeated and occurred more than once.

Is there any short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**formula with 3D reference**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx) on sheet RWS:

```
=IF(MAX(FREQUENCY(WS1:WS5!A1,WS1:WS5!A1))>1,0,1)
```

Comment: +1 or alternatively: `=IF(MAX(FREQUENCY(WS1:WS5!A1,WS1:WS5!A1))>1,0,1)`